# Why does Pascal's principle apply to a Hydraulic jack but not to stream lines in a stream tube?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, fluid-statics

Pascal's principle says that

> the pressure applied at one point in an enclosed fluid under
>   equilibrium conditions is transmitted equally to all parts of the
>   fluid

and thus the pressure in e.g. a hydraulic jack is equal everywhere.

However, in a stream tube, the pressure at the narrow end will be greater than the pressure at the wider end. Therefore, Pascal's principle does not apply to a stream tube and we need to use Bernoulli's equation to model the stream tube phenomenom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pascal's Principle applies only to *confined/enclosed* fluids. When fluid is flowing through a stream tube, it is not completely confined (the tube has two open ends, after all; if it didn't, then steady flow wouldn't be possible).